# Problem with binding and unbinding mouse events to custom element

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules, mousemove, custom-element

I am trying to add "move by mouse" functionality to my CustomElement to enable it to move by mouse drag, by this simple function as below. 
But it has a lot of lag and the event does not attach and detach correctly on "mouseup" or "mousedown" events.
I couldn't found why this happens because it works normally on simple "div" elements.

drag functionality:

```js
//drag-element.js
export default function dragElement(elm) {
  const header = elm.Cardheader;
  header.style.cursor = "all-scroll";
  let [initX, initY] = [0, 0];
  let mousedown = false;

  let mousemoveEventHandler = function(e) {
    if (mousedown) {
      elm.style.top = `${e.clientY - initY}px`;
      elm.style.left = `${e.clientX - initX}px`;
    }
  };

  let mousedownEventHandler = function(e) {
    mousedown = true;
    header.onmousemove = mousemoveEventHandler;
    initX = e.clientX - elm.offsetLeft;
    initY = e.clientY - elm.offsetTop;
  };

  let mouseupEventHandler = function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    header.onmousemove = null;
  };

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupEventHandler);

  header.onmousedown = mousedownEventHandler;
}
```

Custom Element:

```js
//content-card.js
export default class ContentCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `
            :host {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #fff;
                width: 50%;
                margin: 20px auto;
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid #eee;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #444;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .header {
                background-color: #eee;
                min-height: 20px;
                display: block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .body {
                min-height: 150px;
                display: block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
        `;

    this.Cardheader = document.createElement("div");
    this.Cardheader.setAttribute("class", "header");

    this.Cardbody = document.createElement("div");
    this.Cardbody.setAttribute("class", "body");

    this.Cardheader.textContent = this.getAttribute("subject");
    this.Cardbody.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("content");

    shadow.appendChild(this.Cardheader);
    shadow.appendChild(this.Cardbody);
    shadow.appendChild(style);

  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["subject", "content"];
  }

  get subject() {
    return this.Cardheader.textContent;
  }
  set subject(val) {
    this.Cardheader.textContent = val;
  }

  get content() {
    return this.Cardbody.innerHTML;
  }

  set content(val) {
    this.Cardbody.innerHTML = val;
  }

  connectedCallback() {}

  disconnectedCallback() {}

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) return;

    switch (name) {
      case "subject":
        this.subjetct = newValue;
        break;
      case "content":
        this.content = newValue;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  adoptedCallback() {}
}
```

main Javascript:

```js
//index.js
import ContentCard from "./content-card.js";
import ContentCard from "./drag-element.js";


customElements.define("content-card", ContentCard);

let cCard = new ContentCard();

document.body.appendChild(cCard);

dragElement(cCard);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <content-card subject="subject" content="Content"></content-card>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `document.getElementById;`

Comment: I edited the code. It was just a mistake on pasting the code.

Comment: You may use profiler in browser developer tools to record lagging and see what causes it. Unbinding may not work because event is part of custom element, so rather add some attribute to block event from happening. So if attribute x is set to true - only do e.preventDefault().

Comment: ok at first glance I have a few questions. How do you expect the mousemove and mousedown event handler to access the mousedown variable when they are executed as as call backs? this would at least explain why it wont stick when you let go of it

Comment: @fubar, they have access to it because of javascript "Closures"

Comment: Thank you @Zydnar. I will tray check it with the profiler but can't understand why binding and unbinding should be different with normal elements.

Comment: so another thing that I have a question about is `elm.style.top = e.clientY - initY;` not being  `elm.style.top = (e.clientY - initY) + 'px';` since the element wont stick otherwise to its new position and the line doesn't make sense is this intended?

Comment: Thank you @fubar it was typing mistake I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks of @fubar and @Zydnar I change Style of host and removed the `margin: 20 auto`
and also add `event.preventDefault()` to mousedown event and lag decreased a lot and also unbinding problem fixed in the separate browser.
(But it has still, the problem with code snippets) but it does not occur in the real page.
I add some improvement to drag methods:

1- instead of setting `elm.style.top` and `elm.style.left` I used `elm.style.transform =`translate(${left}px,${top}px)`;`
2- instead of using `element.offsetLeft` and `element.offsetTop` I used 
`let rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();` and `rect,left` and `rect.top`

```js
//drag-element.js
function dragElement(elm) {
  const header = elm.Cardheader;
  header.style.cursor = "all-scroll";
  let [initX, initY] = [0, 0];
  let mousedown = false;

  let mousemoveEventHandler = function(e) {
    if (mousedown) {
        let top = e.clientY - initY || elm.top;
        let left = e.clientX - initX || elm.left;
        elm.style.transform = `translate(${left}px,${top}px)`;
    }
  };

  let mousedownEventHandler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mousedown = true;
    header.onmousemove = mousemoveEventHandler;
    let rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    initX = e.clientX - rect.left;
    initY = e.clientY - rect.top;
  };

  let mouseupEventHandler = function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    header.onmousemove = null;
  };

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupEventHandler);

  header.onmousedown = mousedownEventHandler;
}

//content-card.js
class ContentCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `
            :host {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #fff;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
                width: 50%;
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid #eee;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #444;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .header {
                background-color: #eee;
                min-height: 20px;
                display: block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .body {
                min-height: 150px;
                display: block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
        `;

    this.Cardheader = document.createElement("div");
    this.Cardheader.setAttribute("class", "header");

    this.Cardbody = document.createElement("div");
    this.Cardbody.setAttribute("class", "body");

    this.Cardheader.textContent = this.getAttribute("subject");
    this.Cardbody.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("content");

    shadow.appendChild(this.Cardheader);
    shadow.appendChild(this.Cardbody);
    shadow.appendChild(style);

  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["subject", "content"];
  }

  get subject() {
    return this.Cardheader.textContent;
  }
  set subject(val) {
    this.Cardheader.textContent = val;
  }

  get content() {
    return this.Cardbody.innerHTML;
  }

  set content(val) {
    this.Cardbody.innerHTML = val;
  }

  connectedCallback() {}

  disconnectedCallback() {}

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) return;

    switch (name) {
      case "subject":
        this.subjetct = newValue;
        break;
      case "content":
        this.content = newValue;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  adoptedCallback() {}
}

customElements.define("content-card", ContentCard);

let cCard = new ContentCard();

document.body.appendChild(cCard);

dragElement(cCard);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the `px` fixed the sticking and the funny snapping behavior at the start can be offset by adding the padding of the header to the `initY`. This caused by the header having padding and the offset of the `elm` not accounting for this and the `header` snaped to the mouse position so it was snapping with `15px` to much which caused the mouse to move out of the header and dropping the element. Any one know a the correct prop here? This will answer your question why it was kind of weird...

Regarding the laggy bit you might have to look at maybe skipping a few events.

```js
//drag-element.js
function dragElement(elm) {
  const header = elm.Cardheader;
  header.style.cursor = "all-scroll";
  let [initX, initY] = [0, 0];
  let mousedown = false;

  let mousemoveEventHandler = function(e) {
    if (mousedown) {
      elm.style.top = `${e.clientY - initY}px`;
      elm.style.left = `${e.clientX - initX}px`;
    }
  };

  let mousedownEventHandler = function(e) {
    mousedown = true;
    elm.onmousemove = mousemoveEventHandler;
    initX = e.clientX - elm.offsetLeft;
    initY = e.clientY - elm.offsetTop + 15;
  };

  let mouseupEventHandler = function(e) {
    mousedown = false;
    header.onmousemove = null;
  };

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupEventHandler);

  header.onmousedown = mousedownEventHandler;
}

//content-card.js
class ContentCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `
            :host {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #fff;
                width: 50%;
                margin: 20px auto;
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid #eee;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px #444;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .header {
                background-color: #eee;
                min-height: 20px;
                display: block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
            .body {
                min-height: 150px;
                display: block;
                padding: 15px;
            }
        `;

    this.Cardheader = document.createElement("div");
    this.Cardheader.setAttribute("class", "header");

    this.Cardbody = document.createElement("div");
    this.Cardbody.setAttribute("class", "body");

    this.Cardheader.textContent = this.getAttribute("subject");
    this.Cardbody.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("content");

    shadow.appendChild(this.Cardheader);
    shadow.appendChild(this.Cardbody);
    shadow.appendChild(style);

  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["subject", "content"];
  }

  get subject() {
    return this.Cardheader.textContent;
  }
  set subject(val) {
    this.Cardheader.textContent = val;
  }

  get content() {
    return this.Cardbody.innerHTML;
  }

  set content(val) {
    this.Cardbody.innerHTML = val;
  }

  connectedCallback() {}

  disconnectedCallback() {}

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) return;

    switch (name) {
      case "subject":
        this.subjetct = newValue;
        break;
      case "content":
        this.content = newValue;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  adoptedCallback() {}
}

customElements.define("content-card", ContentCard);

let cCard = new ContentCard();

document.body.appendChild(cCard);

dragElement(cCard);
```